# Azure Notification Hubs Send Notification to Specific Device

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I'm currently replacing PostSharp with Azure Notification Hub as post sharp seems to have stopped working in Azure. I have setup my app and it registers its device tag with Azure. I have tested a push notification from the Azure portal broadcasting to all and it works.

However I want to amend my Web API project so I can send notifications to a specific device. Here the code that I have got so far where device tag is the device tag of the iPhone:

```
var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello from .NET!\"}}";
       await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert, new List<string> { deviceTag });
```

This does not work however. I thought I could just send the device tag similar to how post sharp works? I'm a little confused as I know this device has successfully registered with the hub in Azure, because if I do a test broadcast from the portal it receives a notification. How do I amend my API code to send to just a specific device? I came across this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/ but it seems odd, as I already know the device token. Is it possible to send a notification to the hub and specify the device tag?

Answer (score 8):

You can definitely send with just the deviceToken.  Tags only work if you have registered them with the deviceHandle first.  The article you found (and it's siblings discussing Google Cloud/Firebase Messaging and iOS) assume that you're using the Registration / Tags mechanism.

You don't need to do that -- you can use the DirectSend or BatchSend notification mechanisms if you just want to talk directly to deviceTokens.  At the "standard" tier you can also use per-message telemetry to find outcomes for calls to Direct or Batch Send.

I started with the Registration oriented examples and then moved to the "direct Send" model -- and we will be developing along those lines.  I don't have the iOS implementation working yet, otherwise I'd give you an example with that.

These links may help:

[Direct Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608572.aspx)
(note that the C# `NotificationHubClient` type has a `SendDirectNotificationAsync` method that implements the Direct Send model).
[Batch Direct Send](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hubs-batch-direct-send/)
[Per-Message-Telemetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608135.aspx)
[Article putting it all together w/ link to GitHub sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/retrieve-platform-notification-system-error-details-with-azure-notification-hubs/)

Comment: This was helpful. First person I could find that was talking about direct send. Everything else just used a semi hack with setting up tags for the userId and sending to that.

Comment: @KristianBarrett  Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

To use DirectSend, you need to work with the abstract class defined

```
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Notification
```

How do you work with this class, and what information needs to be configured for this to work properly?

Comment: You have to create a different notification for each Platform: [Go to Notification class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notification?view=azure-dotnet)